# Run some code when user closes a particular preference screen?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Is there a way to find out when the user closes a particular preference screen? I need to do some updating when the user has changed the preferences in one of my preference screens. Not when the user clicks an actual checkbox, but rather when they press the back button and are done editing the preferences.

So far, all I've been able to find is that I can override my PreferenceActivity's onPause() event, which seems to happen when the user closes the preferences. It works, but I'm not sure this is the best way of going about it.  Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

I couldn't figure out how to actually call a method of my main activity from within the PreferenceActivity. Tried playing around with putExtra() and all sorts of stuff. Eventually i figured - why not do the completely opposite? So instead I implemented the onResume() method in my main activity. Works great for doing stuff when the user closes the preferences, and I can live with the fact that my update method runs every time I resume my app as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the best way to go about it: overriding the onPause() method. It's called right before your activity leaves the foreground.

Comment: OK, thanks! How would I go about calling a method in my main activity when the PreferenceActivity's onPause() event is called? I'm quite new to Java, but from what I've read so far I guess I would need to implement some form of callback? How do I do that?

Answer (score 5):

Well I have been searching for a solution of this issue for weeks up to 2 min ago...
i think i found the way.

```
Preference myPrefScreen = findPreference("myPrefScreen");
    myPrefScreen 
            .setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference prefScreen) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Dialog prefScreenDialog = ((PreferenceScreen) prefScreen)
                            .getDialog();
                    prefScreenDialog
                            .setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface arg0) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                                    ///HERE YOU CAN EXECUTE WHATEVER YOU WANT... 
                                }
                            });
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

You need OnPreferenceClickListener to correctly instantiate the PreferenceScreen Dialog generated only once the PreferenceScreen entry has been tapped on the screen and the new window with the preference children are shown. Otherwise you always getDialog() returns null and there's no way to attach the OnDismissListener to it.

Once you set the OnDismissListener the trick is done!!

I hope this could help.

Happy coding to all!!

Answer (score 0):

`onPause` is the right place to handle and update.